# Have Wordpress posts that belong to multiple categories, exclude some categories from homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

So I have categories A, B, C and D. And also categories 1, 2, 3 and 4. I have posts that can belong to any four of these categories. But I want to exclude anything in categories B, 4 and D from the homepage (and only from the homepage), even though they are also in other categories.

I've been trying plugins and custom code and googling for hours, and I just can't get this to work. The last batch of attempts were variations on this:

```
 <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-32,-99' ); ?>
 <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
 <?php if (! in_category ('-32')); ?>
 <?php x_get_view( 'ethos', 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endwhile; 
 wp_reset_postdata();
 else : ?>
 <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

I figured out how pre_get_posts is supposed to work on a recommendation from elsewhere. This is what I have now, and it's still not working... gist.github.com/megantaylor/fb86fb9cfc026208b928

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code, this line:

`if (! in_category ('-32'));`

looks a little odd.

Firstly, it looks like a double negative – it's not not in the category 32.

Also, can you pass a id as a string `'-32'`? – the docs suggest the id should be a integer.

Does that help in any way?

EDIT:

Also, your `if` should end in a colon, so:

`if(!in_category(32)):`

Comment: yea, somewhere in the three hours i was playing with this, i started stepping on my own feet. ugh....